# A generic error occurred in GDI+ when savin image in stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gdi+

Here is the thing I try to achieve:

- Upload png image to server
- Save it;
- Load the saved image, generate thumbnail;
- Save it in different location;

Everything is fine until I have to save the thumbnail. At first I thought that it is the folder permissions or something, so to verify I tried to save it in a `MemmoryStream` and again I get this "generic GDI+ error", no InnerException or some descriptive StackTrace.
I was thinking that there is something to do with disposing the original Bitmap but still the same. Here is the code:

```
postedFile.SaveAs(fullFilePath);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullFilePath, FileMode.Open);
Image image = Bitmap.FromStream(fs);

Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(thumbsWidth, thumbsHeight, AbortThumbnailPicture, IntPtr.Zero);
image.Dispose();
fs.Dispose();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    thumb.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png); //*** HERE THROWS THE EXCEPTION ***

    using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(fullThumbsPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        ms.WriteTo(fstream);
        fstream.Close();
    }
    ms.Close();
}

// The GetThumbnailImage callback
private bool AbortThumbnailPicture()
{
    return true;
}
```

I don't know what else to do please help.

Comment: It may have something to do with the source image. Did you try with different image files?

Comment: What if you don't dispose of the parent image beforehand? Perhaps it still uses it somehow. Just an idea. In any case, you should probably implement your own resizing function, GetThumbnailImage is rather useless if you don't use it for its intended purpose - returning an embedded thumbnail image. Anything else is better and faster using DrawImage.

Comment: @Luaan if it does not have a thumbnail, I think the `thumb` should be `null` and then the thrown exception would be `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I think I've run into this before, but its been a few years.  I think Luaan is right: try not disposing of the first image until after the thumbnail has been created.

Comment: @KingKing Good point. I'd recommend checking the type of the thumbnail image. Saving a metafile in PNG might be an issue, for example.

Comment: @KingKing If the image does not have an embedded thumbnail, the method scales the image itself.

Comment: What is the type of source image?

Comment: Also, slightly off topic - it's a good idea to save PNGs to MemoryStream first anyway, since PNGs seek in the stream when saving, which means extra unneeded I/O with files, and exceptions with sockets, for example.

Comment: If the image in question has an existing thumbnail image embedded in it that image is returned, I am not sure if by disposing of the main image you in effect are disposing of the thumbnail as well. For example, does it work if you don't call `Dispose` before saving the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank all of you that commented on my question, your comments lead me to the right problem.

So this line of code is just wrong: `Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(thumbsWidth, thumbsHeight, AbortThumbnailPicture, IntPtr.Zero);`

Now I'm using more standardized code that gets the job done very well, here it is:

```
public static Image ResizeImage(Image image, Size size, bool preserveAspectRatio = true)
    {
        int newWidth;
        int newHeight;
        if (preserveAspectRatio)
        {
            var originalWidth = image.Width;
            var originalHeight = image.Height;
            var percentWidth = size.Width / (float)originalWidth;
            var percentHeight = size.Height / (float)originalHeight;
            var percent = percentHeight < percentWidth ? percentHeight : percentWidth;
            newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * percent);
            newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * percent);
        }
        else
        {
            newWidth = size.Width;
            newHeight = size.Height;
        }
        Image newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        using (var graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphicsHandle.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphicsHandle.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }
        return newImage;
    }
```